# Load shapefile in PostgreSQL with intersection rule

Tags: python, postgresql, ogr2ogr

I have one segmentation shapefile vector that I would like to load in a PostgreSQL database. However I need to remove the polygons created in background values of landsat image. Since I have a big amount of features, the performance must be good.

Only the polygon that intersect another polygon can be loaded into the postgres table. This polygon is the same as useful area of image.

Is there any chance to do this operation with spatial restriction when save shapefile in PostgreSQL database?

I need to do it with Python 3.

The first image shows the size of my problem.

[image]

[image]

Comment: is your blade polygon in the DB already? or possibly better, do those small polygons have values based on the raster value (and thus also a value for 'NODATA')?

Comment: @ThingumaBob my polygon isn't is db. Yes, they have mean values of bands, but in the useful area has too.

Comment: you mean there are `NODATA` values among the polygons you want (and you want to upload them, too)? my point, of coure, would be: if you can distinguish the ones outside of your 'useful area' by their value, it would be a lot easier (and faster) to get your desired import by doing so e.g. with a `-where` flag.

Comment: Hummmm. Yes. I will try.